# List of interesting math podcasts?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, online-resources

[mathfactor](http://mathfactor.uark.edu/) is one I listen to.  Does anyone else have a recommendation?

Comment: Should be community wiki, since it's asking for a sorted list of resources?

Comment: Yes, any question that asks users to create a list or poll should definitely be made community wiki. I converted this question.

Comment: Why is this tagged off topic? Surely if it needs this tag then it should be closed...

Comment: People sure tag this post for reason bro.

Answer (score 20):

I would like to draw attention to the beautifully produced podcast [Relatively Prime](http://relprime.com/) hosted by Samuel Hansen, which was funded through a successful [kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/386612592/relatively-prime-stories-from-the-mathematical-dom) campaign. All eight episodes are well worth a listen and include interviews with some very high profile and influential mathematicians.

Answer (score 18):

Peter Rowlett has a couple mathematical podcasts.  [Travels in a Mathematical World](http://www.travelsinamathematicalworld.co.uk/) produced 64 episodes, but recently stopped.  He has a new podcast [Math / Maths](http://www.pulse-project.org/pulsemathsmaths/) that he co-hosts with Samuel Hansen.

Samuel Hansen also has a couple other podcasts: [Strongly Connected Components](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/strongly-connected-components/id334982081) and [Permutations and Combinations](http://cppodcast.libsyn.com/). Strongly Connected Components is more mathematical and often features interviews.  I've only listened to Permutations and Combinations once or twice.  I believe it's more of a comedy show.

Answer (score 16):

[More or Less](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/moreorless) is a BBC Radio 4 programme about maths and statistics in the news, and there is a free podcast. It's presented by [Tim Harford](http://timharford.com/), the Undercover Economist from the [Financial Times](http://www.ft.com/home/uk).

Comment: Oh, wow, Tim Harford!  :)

Comment: Yeah! Tim Harford +1

Answer (score 14):

The BBC has a History of Mathematics series. Worth listening to. http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/maths

Answer (score 13):

Recently I created a [curated list](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/en/resources-channels-podcast-to-learn-math/) about all Math resources I am subscribed to ( **blogs**, **Youtube Channels** and **podcasts**). Here are some podcasts:

- [Relatively Prime](http://relprime.com/)
- [Ben Ben Blue](http://benbenandblue.libsyn.com/rss) (This is from the creator of the youtube channel 3 Brown 1 Blue.)

And Interesting *Channels*:

- [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw)
- [Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1_uAIS3r8Vu6JjXWvastJg)
- [NumberPhile](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoxcjq-8xIDTYp3uz647V5A)
- [PBS Infinite Series](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCs4aHmggTfFrpkPcWSaBN9g)
- [StandUpMaths](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSju5G2aFaWMqn-_0YBtq5A)

Comment: I listened to the first couple episodes of Relatively Prime and it wasn't great. Perhaps later episodes are better (as is usually the case with podcasts).

Comment: Yup, wasn't that great. A little bit disappointing but I think it is fine for some people.

Answer (score 10):

[Strongly Connected components](http://www.acmescience.com/?cat=14)
 is a great podcast about interviews to several american mathematicians.

Answer (score 10):

I think [Math for Primates](http://www.mathforprimates.com/) is kind of good.

Answer (score 8):

[My favorite theorem](https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/episode-0-your-hosts-favorite-theorems/id1262231136?i=1000390133340&mt=2) is pretty good.

Answer (score 7):

The [Science of Better](http://www.scienceofbetter.org/podcast/) is a good applied math podcast.  Features applications of operations research to practical problems.

Comment: Looks like the link is now broken.

Answer (score 6):

I listen to [Math Mutation Podcast](http://www.aracnet.com/~eseligma/mm/). The topics are interesting and understandable by a layman.

Answer (score 5):

MAA podcast has an archive. http://www.maa.org/audio%20clips/podcast/podcast.html
I think it has stopped producing new ones.

Answer (score 5):

The Numberphile Podcast is relatively new.
Brady Haran, the maker of the Numberphile YouTube channel, interviews famous mathematicians about their life and their favorite math bits.

https://www.numberphile.com/podcast

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat self promotion but Dave Gale and Colin Beveridge record the *Wrong, But Useful* Podcast on an approximately monthly basis.

http://www.flyingcoloursmaths.co.uk/category/podcasts/

Also can be found on iTunes.

Answer (score 4):

I think http://lineardigressions.com/ is enticing. Especially if you're interests involve machine learning.

Answer (score 4):

Breakingmathpodcast.com

A new podcast series with a lot of diverse topics based out of the University of New Mexico. I think I've listened to all of the full episodes in a week (There are about 20). They discuss everything from the Navier Stokes equations, to Hacking culture.

Good depth for those who are looking for overviews. I am an applied math undergraduate with a background in the social sciences, and I follow most things just fine.

Their primary objective is to make math accessible to everyone. They attempt to break down higher-level math concepts in a way that an 8th-grade student will understand.

Plus...... It's rather funny.

-Cody

Comment: The soundcloud link from their site is dead.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [Modellansatz](http://www.math.kit.edu/ianm4/seite/modellansatz/en) from the KIT (Karlsruhe, Germany) is a good one. It is a podcast in German but it has many episodes in English since some interview partner do not speak German obviously.
The themes are as divers as [Cerebral Flow](http://www.math.kit.edu/ianm4/seite/ma-cerebral-flow/de), [Crime Prevention](http://www.math.kit.edu/ianm4/seite/ma-crime-prevention/de), [Nonlinear Electrodynamics](http://www.math.kit.edu/ianm4/seite/ma-electrodynamics/de), ...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I was looking for a good math podcast a while back and I didn't find one that fit my fancy, so I actually started one at my university interviewing mathematicians about what it is like to do research and work in academia. I've linked to it below if you want to check it out!

[Group Theory Podcast](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCohVXiRV-SggN8UaUInClUQ)

Answer (score 2):

The YouTube channel [Sense Makes Math](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCI3K1J8do2RAa0wC60YGK5Q) has a a video-podcast called {Q,E,D}. Sometimes they do proofs so they use a whiteboard.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out the Lxt's Tylk Mzth podcast on Spotify [here](https://open.spotify.com/show/7E13NGR4DX5Ak3NeOs1fCq):

It's pretty much a chill and casual podcast about abstract algebra and math jokes in a someone rigorous way. Edit: I think it's also on Soundcloud.

Comment: Please add a link or correct the spelling, if i google "Lxt's Tylk Mzth podcast on Spotify" I get 0 results.

Comment: That's the correct spelling.

Comment: Great, well seeing as all the episodes were uploaded yesterday I think links are helpful as Google won't index it yet. Did you make this podcast?

Comment: My apologies for not including the link at first. Yup.

Answer (score 2):

I enjoy My Favorite Theorem. This podcast helped broaden my mathematical knowledge and diversified my interests by showcasing a broad range of mathematicians and their theorems. It's pretty neat!

Answer (score -4):

I have a math podcast called the Life and Math Podcast (LaMP). I interview mathematicians from a wide variety of backgrounds to learn about

1. Their path in life from high school to where they are now, and
2. The math they do.

Each interview is released as 2 episodes, a "Life" and a "Math". It's up as audio or video format.

So far I've had a former WWE-style pro wrestler, a guy who dropped out of undergrad to join the Army, and a prof who didn't get into a single college or university who all became mathematicians.

The audio is available on most podcast hosts (apple, spotify, etc). Here's a [link](https://soundcloud.com/kyle-taljan) to the podcast on soundcloud.

The video version is on Youtube ([link to Youtube channel](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLv6uM2DOOtPbANJ9AWlLwED-fmyb4Pajw)). I also make instructional videos on topics that come up in the interview which can be found on the Youtube channel. Things like "What are categories, functors, & natural transformations?". Enough to help students follow along with the interviews.

Everything can also all be found at https://lifeandmath.com. Roughly one interview every 1-2 weeks.

Comment: [Can I support my product on this site ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/product-support)

Answer (score -6):

There's a new maths podcast that you may be interested in that reviews "Maths at the Movies: Interstellar plus SPECIAL GUEST" in its first series. It's a slightly anarchic look at movies, mathematics, and life: [www.mathsat.co.uk](http://www.mathsat.co.uk/search?updated-max=2018-01-31T15:58:00Z&max-results=7) ([direct link to podcast MP3 audio](https://archive.org/download/InterstellarDraft/Interstellar_draft.mp3)). There are some additional podcasts included as [other blog entries](http://www.mathsat.co.uk/).