# List of Interesting Math Blogs

Tags: soft-question, big-list, online-resources

I have the one or other interesting Math blog in my feedreader that I follow. It would be interesting to compile a list of Math blogs that are interesting to read, and do not require research-level math skills.

I'll start with my entries:

- [Division By Zero](http://divisbyzero.com/)
- [Tanya Khovanova’s Math Blog](http://blog.tanyakhovanova.com/)

Comment: "List of X" questions generally [are frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason).

Comment: Yes you're right. I'd like to quote Robert Cartaino (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3/list-of-interesting-math-podcasts) on this one: "[...] *any question that asks users to create a list or poll should definitely be made community wiki* [...]". I think it would interesting to compile a list of math blogs that do not require research-level math skills to be followed, since I personally find it quite difficult to find such Math blogs. In the end the community or a moderator has to decide if this question shall be closed; I for one do not hope that it gets closed :)

Comment: @badp: considering the upvotes, I think it's safe to say people like this question. I for one am very interested in seeing answers to this.

Comment: Eh! This Division by Zero guy stole my name!

Comment: If it helps, you can refer to my personal website, where I blog about Mathematical Shortcuts : http://www.sapnaedu.in

Comment: I am studying theoretical physics, and recently I have been working on a math blog called Derive It (https://derive-it.com). So far it is mostly about limits and derivatives. I hope you like it. Here's the Facebook Page: https://www.facebook.com/Derive-It-103153465094058

Comment: https://blog.math.tools has regular topics on math.

Answer (score 37):

Not always pure math, but I think John Baez' [This Week in Mathematical Physics](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/this.week.html) contains a lot of really interesting math reads.

I should add Terry Tao's [What's new](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/). It's a very active math blog (both in posts and comments) and definitely covers some cutting edge math, even if it can be way over my head.

Comment: I have been watching this: it is neither obtuse or pandering.  Definitely 5-star!

Answer (score 31):

[Timothy Gowers'](http://gowers.wordpress.com/) blog is excellent.  Like Terence Tao, he is both a Fields medalist and an excellent writer.  Together their blogs were my first real introduction into how professional mathematicians think, and their writing has taught me a lot, both about mathematics and about mathematical writing.  If you are a serious student of mathematics you will find all the blogs you need by scrolling through their blogrolls.

Comment: I know that this is frowned upon,but I can't stop myself from saying
"me too" :)

Answer (score 21):

Here is an entire [list of math blogs](http://www.mathblogging.org/).

Comment: Just letting you know, when I clicked the link, it said "DNS address could not be found."

Answer (score 19):

I find [Annoying Precision](http://qchu.wordpress.com/) to be wonderfully readable, and has many many interesting topics. Additionally, [Rigorous Trivialities](http://rigtriv.wordpress.com/) is a bit higher level, but has a really useful intro to Algebraic Geometry.

Answer (score 17):

Gil Kalai's [blog](http://gilkalai.wordpress.com/) is pretty awesome. Mostly covers combinatorics.

Answer (score 15):

[Secret Blogging Seminar](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/)

Comment: The archives of SBS have some real gems.  In particular there is an amazing discussion of the merits of doing algebraic geometry without prime ideals, which recently came up in an answer here: http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/algebraic-geometry-without-prime-ideals/

Answer (score 10):

[Math-blog](http://math-blog.com/) is one I have in my google reader and I just found this one through google reader but it's a little over my head:[The Unapologetic Mathematician](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/upper-and-lower-ordinate-sets/)

Comment: I like The Unapologetic Mathematician's blog (at least the mathematical content of it) for two main reasons.  First, he introduces topics as they appear in the standard undergraduate curriculum - but then takes them to the next level within the first paragraph of a post.  From there he is able to keep his feet on the ground while revealing "deeper meaning" to the topic.  Second, since he has been doing it so long the site has become quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 9):

Some more that didn't appear in other answers:

- [Mathbabe](http://mathbabe.wordpress.com)
- [David Edwards](http://davidaedwards.tumblr.com)
- [Proof Math Is Beautiful](http://proofmathisbeautiful.tumblr.com)
- [Into the Continuum](http://intothecontinuum.tumblr.com)
- [Low-dimensional topology](http://ldtopology.wordpress.com)
- [Geometry and the Imagination](http://lamington.wordpress.com)
- [Stochastix](http://stochastix.wordpress.com)
- [Sketches of Topology](http://sketchesoftopology.wordpress.com)

Additionally, I write [isomorphismes](http://isomorphismes.tumblr.com/tagged/mathematics) which is more about the intersection of maths with humanities than maths *per se*.

Answer (score 8):

It isn't quite a blog, but [Steven Strogatz's 15 part series](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/category/steven-strogatz/) for the New York Times was excellent.

Answer (score 8):

[Math ∩ Programming](http://jeremykun.com). The name is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 7):

http://amathew.wordpress.com/

He climbs Mount Bourbaki with the grace of a leaping gazelle.

Answer (score 6):

Not a pure math blog, but it's one of the most fascinating blogs in my RSS.

[Futility Closet](http://www.futilitycloset.com/)

Answer (score 6):

Always enjoyed [Shtetl-Optimized by Scott Aaronson](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/).

Comment: Me too, but that one is more computer science (and to go even further, (quantum) complexity) related.

Answer (score 5):

[Gödel’s Lost Letter and P=NP](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com) is a very well written and active blog (also, both in posts as in reactions). Especially for people with an interest in theoretical computer science.

Answer (score 4):

John D Cook writes [The Endeavor](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/)

One of the MathWorks blogs: [Loren on the Art of Matlab](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/)

... a few more:

[eon](http://unimodular.net/blog/?p=185)

[Peter Cameron's Blog](http://cameroncounts.wordpress.com/)

[Walking Randomly](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/)

[Todd and Vishal's Blog](http://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/)

(Check their blogrolls for more)

Answer (score 4):

Although it's still new, I hope that my [blog](http://www.mixedmath.wordpress.com) is pretty interesting. It details some of my recent research, things I currently am looking into, and some recreational math along the way. (I also use it as a teaching supplement to my students, but I bet that won't be too interesting here).

Comment: Not math specific but interesting.

Answer (score 3):

[Cedric Villani's news](http://cedricvillani.org/) is relatively new and looks quite interesting (even when messed with by google translate).

Answer (score 3):

For statistics and related topics, see the very interesting:

http://andrewgelman.com/

See his blogroll for more of the same!

Answer (score 2):

[Wild about Math!](http://wildaboutmath.com/) and [SatMathBlog](http://satmathblog.com/) (more for amateurs)

Answer (score 2):

For those who are teaching in high school or what not: [gaussianmath](http://www.gaussianmath.com/blog.html)

Comment: link is dead (2020)

Answer (score 2):

If your interests extend to game theory and mathematical economics look at [here](http://agtb.wordpress.com/)  and   [here](http://marketdesigner.blogspot.com/).

Answer (score 2):

For those of you that can speak french, there is the wonderful http://images.math.cnrs.fr/.

It is aimed at a wide public, but all articles are written by researchers and most are fascinating!