# Mathematical suggestions for a long commute

Tags: soft-question

I have quite a long commute on my way to my university (about 75 minutes) so I was wondering if there's a math-related podcast or something of the sort you'd recommend. Exercises are appreciated as well, but they should be conceptual (or at least light on computations, so I could solve them in my head), since I can't write while on my commute (I don't drive, but trains are awfully crowded here). Any other suggestion is welcome!

As a sidenote, I've taken multivariable calculus and elementary courses covering linear algebra, sequences and series, number theory and a little bit of complex analysis.

Comment: It'd be nice if an admin could CW this.

Comment: (+1) Good question. While I was in grad school, I went to see my future wife just about every weekend. The drive was about 4 hours each way, my car had no CD player, and the radio didn't work well. Those drives were great times to work on proofs/homework. I would recommend re-reading homework problems or course notes just before the commute so you can ponder them while you travel.

Comment: @Bill: That's what I'm currently doing; the thing is I'm taking multivariable calculus and an algebra course which is an introduction to a variety of topics, as combinatorics and number theory. So most exercises are a tad heavy on computations, as opposed to more abstract reasoning. It's nice to think about proofs to the theorems seen in class though. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Ahh, I see. You just need to take a good course in topology, functional analysis, or Lie theory :) I guess I was thinking more of graduate courses which are chock full of conceptual problems.

Comment: @Bill: I know, hopefully in a couple of years :)

Comment: @Fernando: I suggest you add a bit on your background, since suggestions like topology and such would be coming up eventually, you may want to somewhat set the focus on things *you* can actually do.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Absolutely right. I've taken multivariable calculus and elementary courses covering linear algebra, sequences and series, number theory and a little bit of complex analysis.

Comment: You may want to add this to the post... :-)

Comment: I know that I'm a bit late to the party, but [there's a thread on podcasts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3/list-of-interesting-math-podcasts) here.

Answer (score 10):

It's only  ten episodes of 15 minutes each, so it won't last for long (just two commutes!). But as a stop-gap you can try Marcus du Satoy's [**A Brief History of Mathematics**](http://www.bbc.co.uk/podcasts/series/maths).

Comment: Thanks! This is the kind of thing I was looking for.